# Correct return type for Task of anonymous object from async method in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

What is the best/correct return type for an async method in C#, which returns an anonymous object? My method selects some data via Entity Framework. My best guess was this:

```
public async Task<object> GetStuff() {
  abClass ret = await DoSomethingAsync();
  return new { Param1 = ret.a, Param2 = ret.b };
}
```

But is Task actually the best way to do that, or is there some Task, or something similar?

Comment: This looks like it would return the object, but consuming code would need to use reflection to examine or do anything with the object.  None of this has anything to do with `Task<>`, the same would be true with synchronous methods.  Why not define a class instead of returning an anonymous object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't return an anonymous object from a public method in the first place.

Either return a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) as suggested by @Krzysztof Skowronek or better yet define a type and return an instance of this one:

```
public async Task<YourClass> GetStuff()
{
    abClass ret = await DoSomethingAsync();
    return new YourClass { Param1 = ret.a, Param2 = ret.b };
}
```

Any consumers of your class should thank you for doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, just to examine that theoretically: Would there be a better return type instead of object, if one could not substitute the anonymous object with a class?

Comment: @AndréReichelt: There is no good candiate. That's why you shouldn't expose an anonymous type from a public API.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I changed my code accordingly. I find it a little bit cumbersome, though, that you must name all properties this way. EF only supports empty constructors. From `db.Table.Select(t => new { t.Length, t.Width, t.Height })`, I had to go to `db.Table.Select(t => new Thingy() { Length = t.Length, Width = t.Width, Height = t.Height })`. Is there some way to improve this or make it more readable?

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 7 you can return tuples like in Python - use that instead of anynomous objects:

```
public async Task<(int Param1, double Param2)> GetStuff() {
  abClass ret = await DoSomethingAsync();
  return (ret.A, ret.B);
}

// then you can do:

(int param1, double param2) = await GetStuff(); //or
var stuff = await GetStuff();
var a = stuff.Param1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Because my actual method returns a lot of stuff, I'd better use a class for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your problem has nothing to do with Task.
2. You should not return an anonymous object from a public method, you can do it only if it is an API response.
3. You can create a class as @mm8 said or use a tuple.